# Does Android Emulator have a limit on Bitmap size?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have the following code to generate a bitmap

```
    final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
```

It works fine for every image that I have tried on an Android tablet.  However on the emulator, an image of size 1280 x 720 never works.  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray always returns a null for this image without generating any exceptions.  This makes me wonder if decodeByteArray is "hardware" dependent, and emulator has a limit on Bitmap size that it can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes friend, unfortunately the emulator works well with bitmap textures with limit size of 1024x1024. In Mario Zechner's book ***'beggining android games'***, he says that he advises working with textures sizing the max of 512x512 or 1024x1024, accepting its variations.